# c++ Do-While, Random Words From Array For String With No Repitition

Tags: c++, random, do-while

What I want done is to have an array of words then a string is assigned a random word from the array but no string can have the same word. I tried this but when it runs, it will only do the do-while once then go onto the next do-while leaving duplicates. So what part of what I've written is incorrect and what can I do to fix it?

```
string1 = words[rand()%110];

    do{
        string2 = words[rand()%110];
    }while (string == string1);

    do{
        string3 = words[rand()%110];
    }while (string3 == string1 && string3 == string2);
```

Comment: Your text is almost unintelligible, but you seem to be saying that the program is in a bad state *before it reaches the second loop.* In that case I wonder why you posted the second loop, with its glaring bug that you don't seem to care about.

Comment: Did you intend to write "string2" rather than "string"? If "string" is actually the name of a variable, that loop will run either once or forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first loop seems fine. Maybe you need to write `||` instead of `&&` in the second loop.

PS : In the first loop, is it `while (string2 == string1);` instead of `while (string == string1);` ??

Comment: writing || instead of && worked.

and when asking this question i re wrote the code and wrote string instead of string2

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string getWord(std::vector<std::string> & words, size_t & unusedCount)
{
    size_t index = rand() % unusedCount;
    --unusedCount;
    std::swap(words[index], words[unusedCount]);
    return words[unusedCount];
}

std::vector<std::string> words;
// fill in words here
// ...
size_t wordsCount = words.size();
std::string string1 = getWord(word, wordsCount);
std::string string2 = getWord(word, wordsCount);
std::string string3 = getWord(word, wordsCount);
```